# Conversion from Oracle into SQL Server

Tags: oracle, join, sql-server-2012, sql-scripts

I am trying to interpret Oracle script into SQL script and I see that I am converting the joins wrong as Oracle is using multiple instances of the same table(see orguserfield_c, orguserfield_e, etc in select statment). Could anyone please help me in converting the Oracle into SQL script. Thanks
ORACLE SCRIPT:

```
 select distinct
   wh_acctcommon.effdate
 , wh_acctcommon.acctnbr
 , wh_acctcommon.acctclosecurrmonthyn
 , wh_acctcommon.acctofficer
 , wh_acctcommon.acctofficernbr
 , wh_acctcommon.acctopencurrmonthyn
 , wh_acctcommon.notebal
 , wh_acctcommon.branchname
 , wh_acctcommon.branchorgnbr
 , orguserfield_c.value                 branch_internal_no
 , orguserfield_e.value                 branch_status
 , orguserfield_h.value                 branch_hub_no
 , orguserfield_i.value                 metro_micro
 , orguserfield_j.value                 division
 , userfieldvalue_l.userfieldvaluedesc  division_name
 , orguserfield.value                   region
 , userfieldvalue.userfieldvaluedesc    region_name
 , wh_acctcommon.primaryownercity
 , wh_acctcommon.closedate
 , wh_acctcommon.compoundcalpercd
 , wh_acctcommon.contractdate
 , wh_acctcommon.datelastmaint
 , wh_acctcommon.ownername
 , wh_acctcommon.bankorgnbr
 , wh_acctcommon.intbase
 , wh_acctcommon.intmethcd
 , wh_acctcommon.noteintrate
 , wh_acctcommon.ownersortname
 , wh_acctcommon.loanofficer
 , wh_acctcommon.loanofficersnbr
 , wh_acctcommon.mjaccttypcd
 , wh_acctcommon.managingofficer
 , wh_acctcommon.managingofficernbr
 , acctacctrolepers.persnbr             SBB_Portfolio_Mgr_Nbr
 , persview.fullname                    SBB_Portfolio_Mgr
 , acctacctrolepers_c.persnbr           Orig_Loan_Officer_Nbr
 , persview_d.fullname                  Orig_Loan_Officer
 , acctacctrolepers_e.persnbr           Collection_Officer_Nbr
 , persview_e.fullname                  Collection_Officer
 , wh_acctcommon.datemat
 , wh_acctcommon.intminbalamt
 , wh_acctcommon.intmincalcbaltypcd
 , wh_acctcommon.monthendyn
 , wh_acctcommon.notemtdavgbal
 , wh_acctcommon.nameaddr1
 , wh_acctcommon.nameaddr2
 , wh_acctcommon.nameaddr3
 , wh_acctcommon.nameaddr4
 , wh_acctcommon.nameaddr5
 , wh_acctcommon.notenextratechangedate
 , wh_acctcommon.noteopenamt
 , wh_acctcommon.originatingperson
 , wh_acctcommon.origpersnbr
 , wh_acctcommon.bookbalance
 , wh_acctcommon.businessphone
 , wh_acctcommon.homephone
 , wh_acctcommon.currmiaccttypcd
 , wh_acctcommon.product
 , wh_acctcommon.calcbaltypcd
 , wh_acctcommon.noteratechangecalpercd
 , wh_acctcommon.daysmethcd
 , wh_acctcommon.noteintcalcschednbr
 , wh_acctcommon.ratetypcd
 , wh_acctcommon.primaryownerstate
 , wh_acctcommon.curracctstatcd
 , wh_acctcommon.curracctstateffdate
 , wh_acctcommon.taxidnbr
 , wh_acctcommon.taxrptfororgnbr
 , wh_acctcommon.taxrptforpersnbr
 , wh_acctcommon.currterm
 , wh_acctcommon.primaryownerzipcd
 , wh_acctcommon.primaryownerzipcdsuff
  from OSIBANK.wh_acctcommon
 , OSIBANK.orguserfield
 , OSIBANK.orguserfield     orguserfield_c
 , OSIBANK.orguserfield     orguserfield_e
 , OSIBANK.orguserfield     orguserfield_h
 , OSIBANK.orguserfield     orguserfield_i
 , OSIBANK.orguserfield     orguserfield_j
 , OSIBANK.userfieldvalue
 , OSIBANK.userfieldvalue   userfieldvalue_l
 , OSIBANK.acctacctrolepers
 , OSIBANK.persview
 , OSIBANK.acctacctrolepers acctacctrolepers_c
 , OSIBANK.persview         persview_d
 , OSIBANK.acctacctrolepers acctacctrolepers_e
 , OSIBANK.persview         persview_e
  where (    wh_acctcommon.branchorgnbr         = orguserfield.orgnbr(+)
     and upper(orguserfield.userfieldcd(+)) = 'WREG'
     and orguserfield.userfieldcd           = userfieldvalue.userfieldcd(+)
     and orguserfield.value                 = userfieldvalue.userfieldvalue(+)
    )
and (     wh_acctcommon.branchorgnbr           = orguserfield_c.orgnbr(+)
     and upper(orguserfield_c.userfieldcd(+)) = 'WBRN'
    )
and (    wh_acctcommon.branchorgnbr           = orguserfield_e.orgnbr(+)
     and upper(orguserfield_e.userfieldcd(+)) = 'WBRS'
    )
and (    wh_acctcommon.branchorgnbr           = orguserfield_h.orgnbr(+)
     and upper(orguserfield_h.userfieldcd(+)) = 'WHBN'
    )
and (    wh_acctcommon.branchorgnbr           = orguserfield_i.orgnbr(+)
     and upper(orguserfield_i.userfieldcd(+)) = 'WSIZ'
    )
and (    wh_acctcommon.branchorgnbr           = orguserfield_j.orgnbr(+)
     and upper(orguserfield_j.userfieldcd(+)) = 'WDIV'
     and orguserfield_j.userfieldcd           = userfieldvalue_l.userfieldcd(+)
     and orguserfield_j.value                 = userfieldvalue_l.userfieldvalue(+)
    )
and (    wh_acctcommon.acctnbr                 = acctacctrolepers.acctnbr(+)
     and upper(acctacctrolepers.acctrolecd(+)) = 'PMGR'
     and acctacctrolepers.persnbr              = persview.persnbr(+)
    )
and (    wh_acctcommon.acctnbr                 = acctacctrolepers_c.acctnbr(+)
     and acctacctrolepers_c.acctrolecd(+)      = 'OLOF'
     and acctacctrolepers_c.persnbr            = persview_d.persnbr(+)
    )
and (    wh_acctcommon.acctnbr                 = acctacctrolepers_e.acctnbr(+)
     and acctacctrolepers_e.acctrolecd(+)      = 'COFF'
     and acctacctrolepers_e.persnbr            = persview_e.persnbr(+)
    );
```

SQL SCRIPT:

```
  select 
  wh_acctcommon.[EFFDATE]
 , wh_acctcommon.acctnbr
 , wh_acctcommon.acctclosecurrmonthyn
 , wh_acctcommon.acctofficer
 , wh_acctcommon.acctofficernbr
 , wh_acctcommon.acctopencurrmonthyn
 , wh_acctcommon.notebal
 , wh_acctcommon.branchname
 , wh_acctcommon.branchorgnbr
 ,OUF.value    AS             'branch_internal_no'
 , OUF.value AS                 'branch_status'
 , OUF.value   AS             'branch_hub_no'
 , OUF.value     AS            'metro_micro'
 , OUF.value       AS          'division'
 , UFV.[USERFIELDVALUEDESC] AS 'division_name'
 , OUF.value               AS    'region'
 , UFV.userfieldvaluedesc  AS  'region_name'
 , wh_acctcommon.primaryownercity
 , wh_acctcommon.closedate
 , wh_acctcommon.compoundcalpercd
 , wh_acctcommon.contractdate
 , wh_acctcommon.datelastmaint
 , wh_acctcommon.ownername
 , wh_acctcommon.bankorgnbr
 , wh_acctcommon.intbase
 , wh_acctcommon.intmethcd
 , wh_acctcommon.noteintrate
 , wh_acctcommon.ownersortname
 , wh_acctcommon.loanofficer
 , wh_acctcommon.loanofficersnbr
 , wh_acctcommon.mjaccttypcd
 , wh_acctcommon.managingofficer
 , wh_acctcommon.managingofficernbr
 , AARP.persnbr  AS           'SBB_Portfolio_Mgr_Nbr'
 , PV.fullname      as              'SBB_Portfolio_Mgr'
 , AARP.persnbr   AS        'Orig_Loan_Officer_Nbr'
 , PV.fullname      AS            'Orig_Loan_Officer'
 , AARP.persnbr      as      'Collection_Officer_Nbr'
 , PV.fullname    AS              'Collection_Officer'
 , wh_acctcommon.datemat
 , wh_acctcommon.intminbalamt
 , wh_acctcommon.intmincalcbaltypcd
 , wh_acctcommon.monthendyn
 , wh_acctcommon.notemtdavgbal
 , wh_acctcommon.nameaddr1
 , wh_acctcommon.nameaddr2
 , wh_acctcommon.nameaddr3
 , wh_acctcommon.nameaddr4
 , wh_acctcommon.nameaddr5
 , wh_acctcommon.notenextratechangedate
 , wh_acctcommon.noteopenamt
 , wh_acctcommon.originatingperson
 , wh_acctcommon.origpersnbr
 , wh_acctcommon.bookbalance
 , wh_acctcommon.businessphone
 , wh_acctcommon.homephone
 , wh_acctcommon.currmiaccttypcd
 , wh_acctcommon.product
 , wh_acctcommon.calcbaltypcd
 , wh_acctcommon.noteratechangecalpercd
 , wh_acctcommon.daysmethcd
 , wh_acctcommon.noteintcalcschednbr
 , wh_acctcommon.ratetypcd
 , wh_acctcommon.primaryownerstate
 , wh_acctcommon.curracctstatcd
 , wh_acctcommon.curracctstateffdate
 , wh_acctcommon.taxidnbr
 , wh_acctcommon.taxrptfororgnbr
 , wh_acctcommon.taxrptforpersnbr
 , wh_acctcommon.currterm
 , wh_acctcommon.primaryownerzipcd
 , wh_acctcommon.primaryownerzipcdsuff


 FROM

                                                   [DNA_Staging].[dbo].[WH_ACCTCOMMON]                    wh_acctcommon

     LEFT OUTER JOIN                 [DNA_Staging].[dbo].orguserfield OUF

                                                                       ON wh_acctcommon.branchorgnbr   =   OUF .orgnbr
                                                                       and upper(OUF.userfieldcd) IN( 'WREG','WBRN','WBRS','WHBN','WSIZ','WDIV')

   LEFT OUTER JOIN                          [DNA_Staging].[dbo].userfieldvalue              UFV

                                                                       ON OUF.userfieldcd  = UFV.userfieldcd
                                                                       and OUF.value  = UFV.userfieldvalue

   LEFT OUTER JOIN                          [DNA_Staging].[dbo].[ACCTACCTROLEPERS]          AARP

                                                                       ON wh_acctcommon.acctnbr                 = AARP.acctnbr
                                                                       and upper(AARP.acctrolecd) IN ('PMGR','OLOF','COFF')

   LEFT OUTER JOIN                   [DNA_Cleanup_DM].[dbo].PERSVIEW                        PV

                                                                       ON AARP.persnbr = PV.persnbr
```

Comment: Use this site to format your query http://sqlformat.org/

Comment: This is not a code translation service. If you have a specific problem, post the **minimal code necessary** to reproduce that problem, explain the problem clearly, and ask a **specific question** related to that problem. *Please port this huge mess of poorly formatted code from one SQL dialect to a different one* is not an acceptable question here.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly about converting the pre-SQL99 Oracle proprietary joins into SQL99 joins. Rather than try to convert your actual code, here is some advice:

- The number of tables in the `from` clause should remain *exactly* the same in both queries. If a table is listed 5 times (with aliases) in the original query, you should have the same 5 instances in the revised query. A fatal flaw with your revised query is that you're trying to collapse these relationships using `in`. You simply can't do that and retain the meaning of the original query.
- Start with the first table and work down, converting each comma in the original `from` clause into an `on`.
- If a relationship in the original `where` clause contains the outer join indicator (`(+)`), then that relationship must go in the outer table's `on` clause. For instance, `a.a = b.a(+)` must become `left join b on a.a = b.a`.